# Fastest way to sort boolean values by LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I wonder which method is faster to sort and select element from MS SQL database by LINQ:

```
.OrderBy(c => c.StartDate)
.ThenBy(c => !c.HasErrors)
.FirstOrDefault();
```

or

```
.OrderBy(c => c.StartDate)
.ThenByDescending(c => c.HasErrors)
.FirstOrDefault();
```

Maybe nagation of every element from table (HasErrors) has influence for time of query execution? Anyone has information on this issue?

Comment: Measure it yourself. It takes less time than waiting for responses here.

Comment: Compare the difference yourself. My guess: it won't matter.

Comment: Well `c.HasErrors` is just `c.HasErrors == true`, probably the `c.HasErrors == false` takes the same time...

Answer (score 1):

The second method is theoretically quicker because you're not first flipping the bit on c.HasErrors before comparing it to TRUE.

The logical steps are as follows

FIRST:

```
1. Order By start date
2. Set c.HasErrors = !c.HasErrors
3. Then Order By c.HasErrors
4. Then return the first record, or null
```

SECOND:

```
1. Order By start date
2. Then Order Descending By c.HasErrors
3. Then return the first record, or null
```

In the first instance, you have an extra step for your query to perform. And it has to perform it for each record, so the longer the list of items, the more times it has to do it.

Answer (score -1):

At first: I don't have any data confirming this, but the difference between the two methods is almost certain not relevant. It's very likely, that the Database-Engine does something similar behind the scenes. So just go with the second version, because it's more readable (the ! might be overlooked in the first approach).

Despite your question: why do you even care about sorting by the boolean value if you just need the first one that fullfills a condition?

What about:

```
.OrderBy(c => c.StartDate).FirstOrDefault(c => c.HasErrors);
```

I know, there is a small difference, because you'll get null if there is no element without an error. Your solution would provide the first element with an error then. But I guess this is what you actually want (blame me if I'm wrong).